# Common high power diode driver architectures?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, linear-regulator, laser, laser-diode, laser-driver

I want to design a circuit to drive a noise sensitive, high power (~2A @1.5V), laser diode. What are the most common drive architectures that commercial laser companies use? Buck converters, linear regulators, op-amp current source, multi-phase SMPS?

Please share any application notes!

[image]

Comment: "drive" could mean anything <-- explain what it means to you

Comment: @Andyaka The drive circuit would be some sort of current or voltage source that could keep the diode at a constant operating point.

Comment: No single answer to this. All methods you list are valid.

Comment: Keeping the diode at a constant operating point usually involves a closed-loop servo that measures the optical power output (maybe with a back photodiode) and modulates the diode current to keep it constant.  Otherwise, temperature, aging etc. will shift the power output.  Though you don't define "operating point" so it's hard to say for sure what you need.  Do you have to modulate the optical output?